# Access a FUSE directory without sudo

Tags: rust, permissions, sudo, fuse

In order to experiment with Rust’s FUSE library ([fuse](https://crates.io/crates/fuse)) I tried running its “hello world” [example](https://github.com/zargony/fuse-rs/blob/master/examples/hello.rs). (NOTE: the example as linked does not compile, but works after some trivial fixes which I omit for the sake of brevity).

The example works fine: when called with a path (in my case, `$HOME/test`), it mounts a FUSE drive with a single `hello.txt` file, containing the classic `Hello World!`.

However, I cannot seem to `ls` the `test` folder, or `cat` the `hello.txt` file, without `sudo`. I tried:

- Running the compiled example itself without `sudo`. It says `permission denied`.
- `chown`ing the folder before mounting (no need, it’s already mine).
- Changing the `UID` and `GID` in the example to my `UID` and `GID`. Doesn’t seem to have any effect.

Here is what I see when I `sudo ls` my home folder, when the FUSE drive is mounted:

[image]

The folder `test` seems to be mine (I’m `abc`), and to have okay permissions. However, no way `ls`ing it without `sudo`. Here is what happens if I `ls` my home without `sudo`:

[image]

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Look at mount options `allow_other`, and the needed `user_allow_other` in `/etc/fuse.conf`. See `man mount.fuse` and `man fusermount`. It depends on your distribution and whether ruby uses the `fusermount` command or just `mount`.

Comment: I compiled the same example on my Ubuntu system and I'm not seeing the problem. How are you mounting `test`?  To start it, I used `cargo run ../temp`.  The binary the example builds mounts automatically. Are you launching it with sudo?

Comment: Hello @Todd! Thanks for the feedback! Yes, I launch it with sudo. Without sudo, the compiled binary just gives me a “permission denied” and panics. So to summarize I do cargo build, then call the generated executable with sudo. It does mount automatically, but then I can’t do much with the mounted drive without sudo.

Comment: @meuh I’m having a bit of trouble navigating your answer. Could you elaborate a bit more? I’ll be googling in the meantime :)

Comment: @meuh I don’t seem to have an /etc/fuse.conf file at all...!

Comment: IT WORKS!! What apparently I had not done was apt install fuse. I had installed only libfuse-dev. Having installed fuse and enabled user_allow_other in /etc/fuse.conf, I could run the thing without sudo, and access everything no problem! Thanks!!